# moveit-noetic, How to attach one object with two end-effectors?

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i'm trying to grasp one object with two arms(A arm and B arm) by this process.

1. Attach object with A arm (l_tool_frame).
2. Attach object with B arm (r_tool_frame).

but it didn't work. when i attach the object to B arm, It is automatically detached from A arm.

I want to attach the object with two arms.
Is there any way to do this?

---

This code is the first way i tried it.

```
moveit_msgs::AttachedCollisionObject l_pad_attach;
pad_attach.link_name = ("l_tool_frame");
pad_attach.object = add_object[0];
current_scene.applyAttachedCollisionObject( pad_attach );

moveit_msgs::AttachedCollisionObject r_pad_attach;
pad_attach.link_name = ("r_tool_frame");
pad_attach.object = add_object[0];
current_scene.applyAttachedCollisionObject( pad_attach );
```

---

This code is the second way i tried it.

```
moveit_msgs::AttachedCollisionObject pad_attach;
pad_attach.link_name = ("l_tool_frame","r_tool_frame");

pad_attach.object = add_object[0];
current_scene.applyAttachedCollisionObject( pad_attach );
```

There is no error, but it is attached only to "r_tool_frame"

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/409927/moveit-noetic,-how-to-attach-one-object-with-two-end-effectors?/) by [don](https://answers.ros.org/users/125248/don/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2022-11-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't think that standard `moveit` supports this. The `moveit` system makes the simplifying assumption that a kinematic chain has only a single "pathway" of links from root to "object". I don't know how much custom code it would take for you to support a closed-loop chain configuration.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2022-11-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [don](https://answers.ros.org/users/125248/don/) on 2023-01-16**:
Thank you for your comment!!

**Comment by [don](https://answers.ros.org/users/125248/don/) on 2023-01-16**:
I was waiting for another comment, but seeing that it hasn't been commented yet, there must be no solution yet!